# How can add tracking code (tradetracker and daisycon) on thank you page

Tags: php, opencart

I have a task, I did research but I still cannot be done.
I am using OpenCart. And I have to add code tracking (from tradetracker and daisycon) to thank you page.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't too comfortable with writing your own extension and your tracking code is JavaScript or HTML you can place it straight into your template. You will find the template you need in:
/catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/success.php

The only problem is that this will now fire every time the page loads. Any success goes to this template.

To fix this you need to go into the controller and make a small addition.

Find:

```
if (isset($this->session->data['order_id'])) {
```

Add a new line below reading:

```
$this->data['enable_tracking'] = TRUE;
```

Then back in the template before simply add an if statement round the tracking code you have added like so:

```
<?php if($enable_tracking === TRUE){ ?>
Delete this line and replace with tracking code
<?php } ?>
```

That should solve your problem.